# How to change width and height in ggplotly? Are there simple methods to change the width and height?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

how to change width and height in ggplotly?

if we use ggplot, it can use ggsave

```
ggsave(filename = "foo300.png", ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
           geom_point(size=2, shape=23) + theme_bw(base_size = 10),
       width = 5, height = 4, dpi = 300, units = "in", device='png')
```

I am using

```
htmltools::browsable(gg[[i]])  

htmltools::save_html(gg[[i]],path)
```

OR

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(print(gg[[i]]), path)
```

to print graph and save HTML but the graph is too small and some words are overlapped but I want a big font, so I hope to change the size of the graph.

I know plolty that can use this to change the width and height.

```
library(plotly)
m <- list(
  l = 50,
  r = 50,
  b = 100,
  t = 100,
  pad = 4
)
p <- plot_ly(x = seq(0, 8), y = seq(0, 8)) %>%
  layout(autosize = F, width = 500, height = 500, margin = m)
```

This is my sample dataset.

```
d1 <-
  data.frame(col_one = c(1, 2, 3, 3),
             col_two = c("aa", "bb", "aa", "bb"))
d2 <-
  data.frame(col_one = c(1, 1, 1, 6),
             col_two = c("bb", "aa", "aa", "bb"))
d3 <-
  data.frame(col_one = c(7, 1, 1, 4),
             col_two = c("cc", "aa", "bb", "bb"))
my.list <- list(d1, d2, d3)

f <- function(table) {
  table <- mapply(function(data, count) {
    sql <-
      sqldf(
        paste0(
          "select *,count(col_one) as count from data where col_one = ",
          count,
          " group by col_one,col_two"
        )
      )
  }, my.list, 1,
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  print(table)

  return (table)
}


f(table = my.list)

f2 <- function(table) {
  num <- length(table)
  chart <- vector(num, mode = "list")
  plotly <- vector(num, mode = "list")

  for (i in 1:length(table)) {
    chart[[i]] <- ggplot(data = table[[i]],
                         aes(x = col_two,
                             y = count,
                             fill = col_two)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.3)

    #print(chart[[2]])

    plotly[[i]] <- ggplotly(chart[[i]])

  }
  return(plotly)
}
f2(f(table = my.list))

save <- function (gg) {
  num <- length(gg)
  print_gg <- vector(num, mode = "list")
  dir <-   "~/test/aa"

  for (i in 1:length(gg)) {
    path <- paste0(dir, i)

    htmltools::browsable(gg[[i]])
    htmltools::save_html(gg[[i]],path)

    #htmlwidgets::saveWidget(print(gg[[i]]), path)
  }
}

save(f2(f(table = my.list)))
```

I have also searched this code but I just wanted to change the width and height.
Must I crate widget first? Are there simple methods to change the width and height?

```
htmlwidgets::createWidget(
  "sigma", 
  x, 
  width = width, 
  height = height,
  sizingPolicy = htmlwidgets::sizingPolicy(
    viewer.padding = 0,
    viewer.paneHeight = 500,
    browser.fill = TRUE
  )
)
```

If I change ggplot to ggplotly in the graph where I should add the width or height? Are there simple methods to change the width and height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not exactly sure this is what you want, but here is my take:

Using your example you create a `ggplot2` graphic and then turn it into a `plotly` object.

```
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
           geom_point(size=2, shape=23) + theme_bw(base_size = 10)

g <- ggplotly(gg)
```

To change the size of your graphic, do as you would usually do with `plotly`.

```
m <- list(
    l = 50,
    r = 50,
    b = 100,
    t = 100,
    pad = 4
)

h <- g %>%
layout(autosize = F, width = 500, height = 500, margin = m)
```

and then you can save as an html document:

```
htmltools::save_html(h,"index.html")
```